# InvocableMethod Through anonymous APEX

Tags: apex, invocable-method

I have an invocablemethod that runs from a process builder that got broken for a few months I had a mapping issue and some fields didn't populate or create for various reasons. In the process builder you only need to pass the Opportunity Id and a string variable and it does the work.

I want to fix my error and pass in Opportunity Ids directly to the method however, I can't figure out how to populate the data to do it.

Example:

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Perform Mapping' description='Performs a ConvertAnything mapping given a list of records.')
global static void generateAndInsertAllRecords(List<ContextRecord> contextRecords)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

ContextRecord is defined here:

```
global class SL_Mapping_Handler extends SL_Mapping_Handler_Helper {

// used for determining which records to perform the mapping from
global class ContextRecord {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Id' required=true)
    global Id Id;
    @InvocableVariable(label='Custom Mapping Identifier')
    global String customMappingIdentifier;
}
```

I'm in anon apex trying to do something like this:

```
SL_Mapping_Handler.ContextRecord cr = new SL_MApping_Handler.ContextRecord();
cr.Id = '006A000000YN0gd';
cr.customMappingIdentifier = 'Opp Auto Renewal';

List<ContextRecord> l = new List<ContextRecord>();
l.add(cr);
SL_Mapping_Handler.generateAndInsertAllRecords(l);
```

But I get an error:

> Line: 3, Column: 1 Invalid type: ContextRecord

Is this possible to do? Is it just a syntax error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to declare the list in your snippet as:

```
List<SL_Mapping_Handler.ContextRecord> l = new List<SL_Mapping_Handler.ContextRecord>();
```

Replaces:

```
List<ContextRecord> l = new List<ContextRecord>();
```

Comment: Beat me to it. The issue was that OP was trying to reference an inner class outside of its containing class. Unless you're inside `SL_Mapping_Handler`, you need to prepend the name of the outer class to be able to use the inner class.