# Record Id sent from scheduled flow to Apex is coming as null in apex

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method

The record sent sent from scheduled flow to Apex is coming as null. When I debug the flow, it is working fine and I could see record id.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the scheduled flow has an input variable of type **Record** that is set to the record that you want to pass to **Apex**.

You also need to make sure that the **Apex** invocable method has a parameter of type [`List<Id>` or `List<sObject>` that can receive the record ID from the flow](https://unhandledsunshine.com/2021/08/12/invocable-methods-how-to-send-data-between-flow-and-apex/).

You can use the `@InvocableVariable` annotation to specify the label and description of the parameter.

For example, you can use the following code to define an Apex invocable method that accepts a list of record ids from a flow:

```
public class MyApexClass {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Process Records' description='Process records from a scheduled flow')
    public static void processRecords(List<Id> recordIds) {
     // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Make sure that the scheduled flow is running in a different context than the Apex invocable method and does not have access to the record ID. This can happen if the scheduled flow is running as a system user or a different user than the one who created or updated the record.

Make sure that the scheduled flow is running in the same context as the Apex invocable method and has access to the record ID. You can use the **Run As** option in the flow properties to specify the user who runs the flow. You can also use the **WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED** clause in your Apex SOQL query to enforce the user's permissions and sharing rules.

For example, you can use the following code to query the record id with security enforcement:

```
public class MyApexClass {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Process Records' description='Process records from a scheduled flow')
    public static void processRecords(List<Id> recordIds) {
    List<sObject> records = [SELECT Id FROM sObject WHERE Id IN :recordIds WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
     // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar Jadav. I did the way you mentioned in the answer. The actual problem was, I was invoking the flow from developer console and it did not work. When I scheduled the flow and wait till it reaches the scheduled time, it worked. Not sure, why invoking it from developer console did not work though.

Comment: Have you passed the required parameter from the anonymous window? See this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250225/invocablemethod-through-anonymous-apex